# Stanford NER tagger generates 'file not found' exception with provided models

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I downloaded [stanford NER 3.4.1](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-ner-2014-08-27.zip), unpacked it, and tried to run named entity recognition on a local file using the default (provided) trained model. I got this:

```
 `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /u/nlp/data/pos_tags_are_useless/egw4-reut.512.clusters (No such file or directory) at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.inputStreamFromFile(IOUtils.java:481)`
```

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the provided models use "distributional similarity features" that require a `.clusters` file at a location specified in the compressed model file (tricky to change). If you're on the stanford network, presumably the required files are there. If not, I found two choices:

1. Download [stanford NER without the distributional similarity features](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-ner-2012-11-11-nodistsim.zip) (slightly degrades performance, but runs faster). disclaimer: I havn't actually tried this, but it should work.
2. Download the distsim file ([look here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/pos-tagger-faq.shtml#distsim)) from stanford and create a sym-link to it so it appears to be in the correct location. In my case on a Mac, I did this:

   - I created a heirarchy of folders `u/nlp/data/pos_tags_are_useless/` somewhere,
   - copied the downloaded `egw4-reut.512.clusters` file there,
   - then `cd /; sudo ln -s <somewhere>/u`.

Comment: This is a bug in the classifier models released with version 3.4.1. While your workaround works, the distributional similarity clusters should be within the serialized model (and were in previous releases). I'll re-release things with fixed models in a day or so once I've remade the models....

Comment: There seems to be the same or a similar problem with the German and Spanish models available as of 2015-10-25 from http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml ? At least when I attempt to load using the version 3.4 libraries?

Comment: I would recommend making a comment on @ChristopherManning's answer, that way he will hear about it (:

Answer (score 2):

This was an error in the model files accompanying the initial release of the v3.4.1 code, and has been fixed. Re-download and all should run fine, without requiring the symlink workaround.